# How to specify an exchange in Pika consumer?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

All in the title : in the methods below from rabbitmq's documentation, we see that publish takes exchange as an argument, but a consumer doesnt.

Also while I am at it, `queue` in consumer is the same as `routing_key` in the publish ? I thought that a routing key was like a tag so that subscribers subscribe to various regex of  tags

code to consume:

```
import pika
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
   print " [x] Received %r" % (body,)

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='hello', no_ack=True)
channel.start_consuming()
```

code to post:

```
import pika
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body='Hello World!')
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting confused about how things work in RabbitMQ. In RabbitMQ you always publish messages to an `Exchange`. An exchange is not different from a logical receiver that will route your message to a `Queue` (or set of queues).

This routing happens differently depending on the type of the `Exchange`. There are different types: Direct, Fanout, Topic and Headers. The way you link an `Exchange` to a `Queue` is using a `Binding`. A binding is defined by a routing key or some headers and it route your messages from a particular exchange to a particular queue.

So, to sum up, you publish messages to an `Exchange`. You consume messages from a `Queue`. And you use a `Binding` to route the messages from the `Exchange` to the `Queue`. That said, there is no way to say a consumer to consume from an `Exchange`.

In your particular case, you are using the routing key 'hello' in your message. That means that you need a `Binding` from your `Exchange` called '' to the `Queue` called 'hello' with the same routing key as your message (which is 'hello'). I would recommend you changing names and having more useful names to see what's going on.

Hope this helps!